# How can I play a recorded sound using a local notification?

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudiorecorder, uilocalnotification

I have an app that requires that the user record their own message to be played back at some future time.  My intent was to do that using UILocalNotification.  Unfortunately, it seems that the sound associated with the local notif has to be stored in the main bundle but the user cannot make a recording and save it in the bundle.

How do I get a user recorded sound file to be played via local notification?

Alternatively - is there a way if the app is not running to capture the local notification (without waiting for the user to respond to an alert) and then play the desired soundfile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a (custom) sound to a `UILocalNotification` by setting its property as follows:

```
localNotification.soundName = @"MySoundFile.wav";
```

Unfortunately, according to the reference, it is not possible to use a sound file that is not stored in the main bundle or is declared by apple:

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a **sound resource in the application’s main bundle** or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system sound.

See also [UILocalNotification Class Reference #soundName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName)

Comment: Are sound files stored in the main bundle necessarily static resources that cannot be changed at runtime?

Comment: Although you can do this in the simulator, it is not possible on iOS devices.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is possible for ios 9, this is what apple documentation says:

> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an app. The sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container.

I tested saving a sound into the Library/Sounds folder then using it with a local notification and it worked fine on iOS 9, after that I tried the same on iOS 8 and it didn't work, so my conclussion was that this is possible for iOS 9 only

You can access the library directory in this way:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let soundsPath = libraryPath + "/Sounds"
```

You have to create the directory if it doesn't exist:

```
fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(soundsPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
```

and you can then save your sounds there.

Comment: Has anybody else managed to get this going? The apple documentation is saying that you should be able to load sound files from Library/Sounds in the app container, but still I have had no success with this, driving me round the bend and holding up my app!

Comment: @Jason, this is the project I created to test it,
https://github.com/chuy47/RecordedSoundNotification
The screen has 3 buttons, "start recording", "stop and save" and "send notification" using the custom sound after 4 seconds, in this project I don't manage the notification when the app is in foreground, to do so you have to implement it in the method "application(application:, didReceiveLocalNotification:)" within the AppDelegate, so for test the custom sound in this project you have to launch the notification (after you saved your sound) and tap the home button to send the app to background.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will check this out this evening, looks like you could be my saviour!

Comment: Gerardo, thanks again I just tested this and I now have it working in my app, brilliant! I was not actually far off it turns out, believe it or not it was down to what I was applying to sound name, I was using the full path to the Library which does not appear to be required, but you do need to add reference to subfolders in bundle. Anyhow all sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

The local notification's `soundname` property can refer to the path of a sound file within the app's bundle.
A sound recording of the user's voice cannot be used as it cannot be saved to the app bundle at runtime.

You cannot have a default notification show up and then open the app and play the recorded voice, unless the user has tapped on the notification.
Which means, if the user is not using the phone, the only chance that they will listen to the recording is if they pick up the phone, unlock it, and tap on the notification. So I believe that this is far from what you want.