# iphone:-play recorded voice with UILocalNotification sound

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am able to record voice using avrecorder but its saving the recorded voice in the path of documents directory and i am unable to find out a way to use it in localNotification sound so any one plz give some light on this issue

code for recording:-

```
-(IBAction)startRecording

{

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];

    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"ccc...%@",documentPath);

    if(toggle)
    {
        toggle = NO;

        recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];


        strRecordedVoice=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"];

        recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strRecordedVoice]];
        NSLog(@"Using Filepath called: %@",recordedTmpFile);
        NSLog(@"Using str: %@",strRecordedVoice);

        recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];





        [recorder setDelegate:self];
                [recorder prepareToRecord];

        [recorder record];

        progressView.progress = 0.0;
        [recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 2];

        lblStatusMsg.text = @"Recording...";
        progressView.progress = 0.0;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



    }
    else
    {
        toggle = YES;

        //Stop the recorder.
        [recorder stop];
    }



}
```

//code for localnotification

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{   
    UILocalNotification *notification =[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    notification.fireDate=fireDate;
    notification.repeatInterval    = 0;
    notification.alertAction       = NSLocalizedString(@"View", @"View");
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ap.strAlarmTitle
                                                         forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    notification.userInfo = userDict;



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    [notification release];

}


Reference:-you can see it its an alarm application which uses uilocalnotification
    itunes.apple.com/us/app/record-alarm-free/id418511936?mt=8
```

Comment: how about setting a notification which will open your app with parameters and then play a sound file?

Comment: will u plz elaborate your idea...thanks

Comment: This is possible for iOS 9 see my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35439941/2051381

Answer (score 4):

You can only use sounds from your App bundle for local notifications

[source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6)

Comment: but i have seen some apps doing it the way i want...if u have idea plz let me know thanks.

Comment: Please link to an app that does this and ill have a look

Comment: notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;  here i wants to use my recorded voice in place of UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName.

Comment: From the doc i linked it quite clearly says: "You can assign the filename of a nonlocalized custom sound in the application’s main bundle to the soundName property"

Comment: the app "record alarm free" uses local notifications but plays the default sound, not the recorded sound

Answer (score 2):

As Martin said, you can only use sound files from the application bundle. Your mentioned app "Record alarm free" also cannot play the recorded sound as notification sound (I've tested).

What you can do is play the sound after the app has been opened from a local notification.

You need to implement this in `didReceiveLocalNotification` **and** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [self playSoundWithNotification:notification];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

  if (notification)
  {
      [self playSoundWithNotification:notification];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[NSLocalNotification *obj PlaySound];