# How to play stored file in document directory as Local Notification sound?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to play a sound track stored in my documents directory . when i get this sound and play it in avplayer with URL as path it works fine, when i give the same url to local notification then it don't work. is there any possible way to play a stored sound as local notification
File path : file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BC43728E-7E45-448E-86C1-54684A82DF5F/Documents/lTTajzrSkCw.m4a

```
func saveAlarm() {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Alarm"
    content.body = "Testing our first alarm"
    if songs.count > 0 {

        let str = Constants.getUrl(for: songs[0].ID , ext: songs[0].ext)?.absoluteString
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(str ?? ""))
    }

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Alarm", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}




static func getUrl(for fileName: String, ext: String) -> URL? {
   guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
   return documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(ext)
}
```

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound), I would check that: 1) The sounds are less than 30", 2) They are in a supported format & 3) They are in `/Library/Sounds` (which in your case are not) or the bundle itself.

Comment: Also, the initializer is pretty clear that it accepts a sound **name**... not a url

Comment: i'm following first two points , i'm stuck in third point , when i append download file from server and mention the path of documents directory it stores at that location , when i try to save it in sounds folder , it don't append the path of Documents/Sounds/song.m4a

Comment: let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            
            documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Sounds", isDirectory: true)

Comment: first i tried this with true later i tried false but nothing worked

Comment: then i tried this 
            var destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Sounds")
            destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioObj.ID)
            destinationUrl.appendPathExtension("m4a")
            print(destinationUrl)

Comment: I would recommend to update your question with all that information (what you have tried so far)

Comment: I have tested [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35439941/5928311) and this should work for you. Please, check it. I used [this audio](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/gs-16b-1c-44100hz.m4a) for local notification

Comment: i have another question , it would be so great if you help me out with that, here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375995/how-to-split-a-long-audio-file-into-small    and the problem mentioned above is solved