# How to split a long audio file into small

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I have an audio file longer than 30 seconds and i want to play it as local notification tune but Apple doesn't allow that. Is there any possible that i can split this file into several files of 30 seconds and play it in sequence, each one with each notification so it would feel like that it's playing synchronously.

Comment: Audio file is stored in library/Sounds directory

Comment: More then 1 minute sound is not a sound its music, so if you want to archive this then you must register as an audio app, and upon receiving a notification, use the AVAudioPlayer to play your file.for background playing [link](https://www.sagorin.org/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/)

Comment: okay i got it , but my issue is something else i want to make chunks of existing file and want to play it in row one after another , is that trimming possible in swift ?

Comment: yeah it is possible but it is not valid way to do.. apple may reject your app and another thing is what if user click on notification before 30 seconds and app is in killes mode? apple allows only 30 to 40 seconds to process in background when app is in kill mode